# Sending App Invites in a React Native app

Tags: facebook, react-native

In the facebook iOS SDK, there is a module called App Invites, allowing to send invites to your app to your friends (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/).

This module does not seem to exist for React Native apps (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native) does anyone know a workaround to make it work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I actually found how to do it digging in react-native-fbsdk.

There is a class called AppInviteDialog that you can use like the ShareDialog described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/sharing

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  AppInviteDialog,
} = FBSDK;


module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {

        return {
            appInviteContent: {
            applinkUrl: 'https://yourapplink.com',
            }
        }
    },

    shareLink: function() {
        var tmp = this;
        AppInviteDialog.canShow(this.state.appInviteContent).then(
            function(canShow) {
                if (canShow) {
                    return AppInviteDialog.show(tmp.state.appInviteContent);
                }
            }
        ).then(
            function(result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                  alert('Share operation was cancelled');
                } else {
                  alert('Share was successful with postId: ' + result.postId);
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                alert('Share failed with error: ' + error);
            }
        );
    }
    ...
});
```

Happy discovery ;)

Comment: This require ejection. Is there any way we do without eject?

Comment: it's not working anymore, is there any other solution plz

Answer (score 0):

I'll use Share Dialogs for sharing on facebook in my case this is working...

```
import { ShareDialog } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
```

```js
shareLinkWithShareDialog() {
  var tmp = this;
  ShareDialog.canShow(this.state.shareLinkContent).then(
    function(canShow) {
      if (canShow) {
        return ShareDialog.show(shareLinkContent = {
         contentType: 'link',
          contentUrl: "https://facebook.com",
  contentDescription: 'Facebook sharing is easy!',
});
      }
    }
  ).then(
    function(result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert('cancelled');
      } else {
        alert('successful with postId: '
          + result.postId);
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      alert('Exception : ' + error.message);
    }
  );
}
```