# react-native-fbsdk app invite dialog error

Tags: react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0, react-native-fbsdk

So I am trying to use [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) `FBAppInviteDialog` to show invitation dialog but I always get this error

[image: error]

I was trying to use this code from [Sending App Invites in a React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025338/sending-app-invites-in-a-react-native-app)

here is my code

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      appInviteContent: {
        applinkUrl: 'https://facebook.com'
      }
    }
  }
  _onPress = () => {
    var tmp = this
    AppInviteDialog.canShow(this.state.appInviteContent).then(
      function (canShow) {
        if (canShow) {
          return AppInviteDialog.show(tmp.state.appInviteContent)
        }
      }
    ).then(
      function (result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          Alert.alert('Share cancelled')
        } else {
          Alert.alert('Share success with postId: ' + result.postId)
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        Alert.alert('Share fail with error: ' + error)
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the `showDialog` works you must first as the example show something like this:

`appInviteContent= {
    contentType: 'link',
    contentUrl: Platform.select({ ios: 'https://iossomething.com',
    android: 'https://androidsomething.com'}),
    contentDescription: 'Check the website!',
};`

Also as I see there in the code you are using the `flow` language.
Check that.